# Broken link. Where may I read that info?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to understand how to use accessTokens in Loopback. I'm reading Loopback docs. But there is a broken link for the document I'm keen on reading. Where can I find that document?

Here is the text:

> Make subsequent API calls using the access token.  Provide the access
>   token in the HTTP header or as a query parameter to the REST API call,
>   as shown in **Making authenticated requests with access tokens**.

Here is the link for **Making authenticated requests with access tokens** that follows nowhere:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Managing+users#Managingusers-Makingauthenticatedrequestswithaccesstokens

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the link has been malformed. The correct link is:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Making+authenticated+requests#Makingauthenticatedrequests-Makingauthenticatedrequestswithaccesstokens